# Model not binding to JSON

Tags: javascript, c#, json, model-view-controller

It looks like my model is not bingding correctly and the fields are all nulls. I have looked online and it seems that none of the solution worked for me. All my properties have setters and getters, the property name of the JSON matches the Model and I am stringifying it. I am setting my headers correctly. Perhaps there is something simple I am not setting. Maybe a missing package? Calling something incorrectly?

On the frontend this is how I am posting my JSON

```
fetch("/Admin/SaveUser", {
    method: "Post",
    headers: {
        "Content": "application/json",
        'Accept': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(userData)
}).then(response => {
    response.json().then(result => {
        UpdateDisplay();
    });
});
```

the content of userData

```
{"UserId":"4dd9f40e-a9ad-418e-9954-e9459c5db1af","FirstName":"Jack","LastName":"","EmployeeCode":"",
 "PhoneNumber":"","Email":"jthor@stackoverflow.com"}
```

my controller method

```
 [HttpPost]
 public JsonResult SaveUser(UserModel user)
 {
    UserModel.UpdateUser(user);
    return Json(false);
 }
```

my Model

```
 public class UserModel
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeCode { get; set; }
    public List<string> UserRoleIds { get; set; }
    public List<string> UserRoleNames { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Roles { get; set; }

    public UserModel()
    {
        UserRoleIds = new List<string>();
        UserRoleNames = new List<string>();
        Roles = new List<SelectListItem>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your model declares UserId as a GUID, which is a numeric type, but your input JSON contains a string for that property. It is unlikely that the model binder will let you get away with that. Try changing the data type of the UserId property to string.

Comment: @DaveHolden The fields are still not binding

Comment: @DaveHolden this is a [.Net Guid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.newguid?view=net-5.0). What he is providing is correct and will bind to that property if he fixes his binding issue. Which system are you coming from that Guid is a numeric type?

Comment: @CallumMorrisson from the Microsoft documentation:
"A GUID is a 128-bit integer (16 bytes) that can be used across all computers and networks wherever a unique identifier is required. Such an identifier has a very low probability of being duplicated."
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid?view=net-5.0

Comment: @DaveHolden unfortunately, finding a bit of documentation that almost supports your original premise doesn't change the fact that **in practice** Guid's aren't a numeric type in .Net. So I guess my original question remains, "Which system are you coming from that Guid is a numeric type?"

Comment: @CallumMorrisson That documentation specifically states that the GUID type is numeric in .NET. Just because we always turn them into strings as soon as we generate them does not alter this fact. The model binder does not know that we do that. Now I am not saying that it is 100% what the issue is here, and based on the OP response it appears to have made no difference changing the UserId property's data type to string so the problem obviously lies elsewhere. Perhaps a change from "Content" to "Content-Type" header may sort it out. As far as I know "Content" is not a standard header name.

Comment: I can tell you with 100% certainty that the model binder, and everything else in .Net is going to know how to parse a string into a Guid. afaik the only way to get an actual numeric type (think `int`, `long`, `double`, `decimal`) into a Guid, is going to be through either an intermediate `string` or a `byte[]`. As I said earlier, **in practice** Guid's are not numeric types in .Net. Don't take my word for it though, spend 20 minutes playing with them in LinqPad or something.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem before and I was able to fix it by adding the `[FromBody]` attribute.

```cs
[HttpPost]
 public JsonResult SaveUser([FromBody] UserModel user)
 {
    UserModel.UpdateUser(user);
    return Json(false);
 }
```

Comment: this is interesting, I am getting a 415 error `UserEdit.js:31 POST https://localhost:44374/Admin/SaveUser 415`

Comment: It seem that I needed to use `[FromForm]` to not get the 415 error but the model is still not binding.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the Content header to "Content-Type", it works for me.

As follows:

```
fetch("/Admin/SaveUser", {
method: "Post",
headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    'Accept': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
},
body: JSON.stringify(userData)
}).then(response => {
    response.json().then(result => {
        UpdateDisplay();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Instead of manually creating the form using HTML I used the html helper `html.beginform` and that worked. IDK why that worked but it did.